# Como retornar todos os resultados do banco de dados [PDO]?

Tags: banco-de-dados, wordpress, pdo

Estou fazendo uma função para retornar todos os resultados de um banco de dados. A função neste exato formato me retorna somente um resultado mas colocando `echo` em cada instrução me retorna todos os resultados.

Como posso fazer com que este código que provavelmente tem um erro de lógica me retorne todos os resultados do banco de dados?

```
try {

    // PDO em ação!
    $pdo = new PDO ( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nomedobanco", "usuariodobanco", "senhadobanco", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") );
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts ORDER BY post_date ASC";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ( $linha = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ) {

        $conteudo = $linha->post_title . "<br>" . $linha->post_date . "<br>";
        return $conteudo;

    }

} catch ...
```

> **Assim retorna todos os resultados ....**

```
while ( $linha = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ) {

    echo $linha->post_title . "<br>" . $linha->post_date . "<br>";

}
```

Comment: `fetchAll()` no lugar de `fetch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma muito simples de efetuar esta tarefa é fazendo o seguinte:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql: hostname=localhost; dbname=example;", "root", "");   
} catch(PDOException $e){
    return $e->getMessage();    
}

// echo $pdo ? "Sim" : "Nao";

$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM jogos");

while($linhas = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    print $linhas->nome . "<br/>";
    // print $linhas->nome . "\t";
}
```

O que inclui  a saída de todos os valores no `looping`.

Fazendo, da maneira como fizeste acima:

```
while($linhas = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $row = $linhas->nome . "<br/>"; 
}
```

A variável `$row` armazena os resultados na ordem de saída, porém apenas o ultimo valor vai persistir, por ela não ser uma `array`, e também por não ter sido instanciada antes.

Sendo que as possíveis soluções seriam:

## 1º

Declarar a variável `$row` fora do `looping`, e depois ir concatenando os resultados.

```
$row="";
while($linhas = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $row .= $linhas->nome . "<br/>";    
}

echo $row;
```

## 2º

Instanciar a variável `$row` dentro do `looping`, só que desta vez, como array, e ir preenchendo cada posição dessa `array` com o respectivo número de resultados retornados.

```
while($linhas = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $row[] = $linhas->nome . "<br/>";   
}

echo $row; // retorna o Notice: Array to string conversion, por se tratar agora de uma array;

foreach($row as $nome){
    echo $nome; 
}
```

## 3º

Ou então desta maneira, talvez a mais simples até.

```
while($linhas = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    print $linhas->nome . "<br/>";
    // print $linhas->nome . "\t";
}
```

Devem existir por aí, ainda várias outras formas de fazer isso, só tens de procurar, ou usar aquela que achares conveniente.

[PDO::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)